# Create a Document Library using REST

Tags: list, document-library, document

How do i create a Document Library using REST?

When i upload a file to document library, i use this url:

http://industrial-ex/sites/tifdemo/enovia/file.txt with a `POST`

What is the url for creating a new Document Library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw i'm using java

Answer (score 2):

[Working with lists and list items with REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn292552.aspx#WorkLists)

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists
method: POST
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 100,
 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'Test' }
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```

Set the BaseTemplate property to 101 to create a document library.

Comment: Don't i need to perform a GET first to get the body content before i make a POST?

Comment: No, you specify the body content. Check out this video, it shows how to perform CRUD operations using the REST API.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIyNs1vXXJA

Comment: I'm still having problem with this issue, is there a tutorial where they do this in Java ? Or if you can show me how to do it please